# Stuck trying to display information from JavaScript form

Tags: javascript, forms

Just working on a class project and I can't figure out what to do next.

I've got a form that is being validated with JavaScript. It's the usual information, name, cc# email, etc.

Well the only tuts I can find relate to how to get the form to validate in the first place, which I've already accomplished.

Now all I need to do is figure out how to get the information that I've captured to display in the confirmation page. I don't need any server side validation if that helps.

Here's a link to the page so far (http://sulley.dm.ucf.edu/~ph652925/dig3716c/assignment4/dinner.html)

Any pointers or references?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

will print whatever value the PHP callback is getting from your form.

=H=

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the GET parameters to forward the info:

```
link.to.new.page.html?param=value&param2=value2
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using PHP. If you're sure you don't want any validation, of any kind, then the simplest way to output what was on the form (with some degree of control over what it looks like) is by using the POST global variable in PHP:

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstName'];
// etc etc for the other fields
?>
```

You can then output whatever you want by using those variables. The 'name' property for the HTML fields corresponds to what goes inside the square brackets in the PHP code above.

Comment: I want to try this, but when I <?php echo $firstname; ?> on process.php I get nothing.

Comment: Could this have something to do with me using window.location to move from dinner.html to process.php?

Comment: Probably, if the form isn't actually being posted to process.php then PHP will not have the information in the form available to it. Make sure the form is being submitted properly (rather than using Javascript) and that should solve the problem.

Comment: Finally got this working, Just took me a bit because one of my javascript functions was interfering. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**First, I would like to note that if you are using any server side application, you should absolutely validate the input on the server script before doing anything with it.** The client side validation is really intended to make it easier for the user to enter the correct information and can be easily hacked or irrelevant if javascript is off... This said, on the client side, you could intercept the submit event, check the different field values. If you have errors, you display error messages, otherwise, you submit the form. example:

if we have this form:

```
<form action"myActionscript.php" method="GET" id="#myForm">
 // form items here
 </form>
```

and then this script (Beware, code not tested)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var f = document.getElementById('myForm');
    if (f.addEventListener) { // addEventListener doesn't work in ie prior ie9
        f.addEventListener('submit', checkForm);
    }else{
        f.attachEvent('submit', checkForm);
    }

   function checkForm() {
       // Check all input fields logic,
       // you could have an errors array and add an error message for each
       // error found. Then you would check the length of the error array,
       // submit the form is the length is 0 or not submit the form
       // and display errors if the length is > 0.

    if (errors.length > 0)
    {
      // iterate through the array, create final error message
      // and display it through an alert or by inserting a new
      // DOM element with the error message in it.
      // [...]
    }else{
        f.submit();
    }
   }
</script>
```

**I have to say that the whole thing would be much easier and certainly more cross-platformed if you used a javascript library like jQuery... ;)**